# Run Active Directory Admin Center as another user

Tags: uac, windows

I am trying to run Active Directory Admin Center (dsac.exe) on Windows 7 as another user by means of creating a shortcut, rather than having to Shift+Right click and specify the user.

On Windows XP I could create a runas shortcut like this (forget for a moment that dsac.exe does not exist in Windows XP):

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\user dsac.exe
```

When I run this on Windows 7, the cmd style windows pops up and asks for the password for DOMAIN\user, but I get the following message:

```
Attempting to start dsac.exe as user "DOMAIN\user" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - dsac.exe
740: The requested operation requires elevation.
```

How do I get Windows 7 to automatically run dsac.exe as a specified user?  I'm happy to fill in a password prompt for the specified user, but would be even happier if there was a solution that cached the password, so I didn't have to enter it more than once a day.

**Update**

The following worked, but feels a bit clunky:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\user "cmd /c Start /B dsac.exe"
```

This prompts for the password, then throws up the UAC dialog, and then opens the app.

Is there a way to do this that bypasses the UAC dialog (without just turning off UAC altogether)?

Comment: Have you tried running the same command from an elevated command prompt? If you run right-click cmd and do 'Run as Administrator' and then run the command, does it still give you the 740 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to bypass UAC is to turn it off in policy.  So I don't think you'll be able to run without the prompt.

To save yourself some trouble though, you can create a desktop shortcut with your command.  When you run the shortcut, it should give you the UAC prompt, but then a command prompt to enter your password.

That way, at least you don't need to key in your command anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RUNAS.EXE /SAVECRED option to cache the password.  This means you only need to enter it once, leaving just a UAC elevation prompt to contend with.  However, you may not want the AD tool to launch without entering a password.  The credentials are securely stored in your profile.

Also, although not truly relevant here, a shortcut can be configured to always use your admin token (properties... advanced... run as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

Go through with following command.
Right Click on your Desktop - Select New+Shortcut copy line below and edit with domain name and password - Click next provide name and click finish.

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:Domainname\username "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc
```

Double click the file. A black screen will appear type your password.
Note : While typing the password characters will be invisible.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work - I don't get any output at all from running the above command.  Anyway - I'm not looking for dsa.msc.  I'm looking for the dashboard style dsac.exe.